# Why rules in public function of model don't do its job correctly?

Tags: yii2

I'm using following rules in model:

```
public function rules() {  
    return [
        [['beurteilung_fachlich', 'beurteilung_persoenlich', 'sonstiges', 'anschreiben'], 'string'],
        [['anschreiben'], 'string', 'max' => 255]
    ];
}
```

Although there is nowhere any restriction for attribute `beurteilung_persoenlich`, I will get error of form validation:

> Beurteilung(fachlich) must not be longer as 255 chars!

[image]

How can this be? 
What do I wrong?
Is there another place for declaring validation rules besides in model?
Database has datatype TEXT without any boundary.

Here is code of form:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'beurteilung_fachlich')>widget(\dosamigos\ckeditor\CKEditor::className(), ['preset' => 'full', 'clientOptions' => ['height' => 200]]) ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed, that following rule will influence all other string attributes, too

```
[['anschreiben'], 'string', 'max' => 255]];
```

I have no idea, why, but after having removed this rule, everything did well.
In order to valid form clientside, I coded like this(in form):

```
$form->field($model, 'anschreiben', ['addon' => ['prepend' => ['content' => 'Anschreiben']]])->widget(TwbsMaxlength::className())->textInput(['maxlength' => 255])->label(false);
```

Comment: You could try to remove anschreiben from the first line, cause it is not neccessary to declare it as string twice: [['beurteilung_fachlich', 'beurteilung_persoenlich', 'sonstiges'], 'string'],

Answer (score 0):

In most of my cases, the javascript / client side validation still work because of caching. Even after the model is modified. Try to Cmd / Ctrl + Shift + R (bypassing the cache), or delete the content of your `backend/web/assets` or `frontend/web/assets`.